# ECS Override LogConfiguration without creating new TaskDefinition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

I'm using AWS Batch to launch multiple container jobs for some larger process. By default it will create a LogGroup and LogStream for each of these jobs. This makes debugging much more difficult when I want to go through each of these jobs.

Instead I want to structure them so all my LogStreams appear under one LogGroup, such as,

```
MyProcess/  # LogGroupName
-> process1/  # LogStream Names
-> process2/
...
-> processN/
```

This is easy enough to achieve by setting up the `logConfiguration` in my `TaskDefinition`, as:

```
"logConfiguration" => Dict(
    "logDriver" => "awslogs",
    "options" => Dict(
        "awslogs-group" => log_group_name,
    ),
),
```

This half-solves my problem. However, the LogStreams inside this LogGroup all will have names as, `logGroupName/Container-Name/ECS-Task-Id`. I'm looking for a way to override this logStreamName so that I can provide it with something more meaningful.

It seems like the only way to do this is by creating a new TaskDefinition for each of these jobs which I would want to do and providing each definition with,

```
"logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "awslogs",
    "options": {
        "awslogs-group": shared_log_group_name,
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": meaningful_log_stream_prefix
    }
}
```

This is not ideal, as I do not want to end up with thousands of slightly-varied TaskDefinitions. I also do not want to use MNP (multi-node-processing) jobs here for a variety of reasons which would solve this issue.

Is there a way to override the logStreamPrefix, or logConfiguration in general? According to the AWS documentation this does not seem possible, but maybe I am missing something?

- [Batch ContainerOverrides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerOverrides.html)
- [ECS AWSLogs Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html)

Comment: The last I checked, this wasn't possible. That isn't one of the things you can set in ECS task overrides.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is not supported yet. A discussion about this problem:
https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/74

Summarizing the linked URL, this is a suggested feature for AWS ECS down the road, however it is not supported at this moment.